# Schedule a node app to run i command tool

Tags: node.js, command

I have a node app that I want to schedule to run in the command tool. Is this possible? I extract data from a source with the command tool and save it to a json file. Can I run my node app in the browser to retrieve the file?

Thanks

Comment: Powershell can do this.

Comment: Not quite sure where the browser part fits in your question. Other than that this is more a shell question than in it is a node one.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [childprocesses](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

Comment: I guess you mean programming a CRON to launch certain task at some time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). For node you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at these options. The browser part is if it's possible to execute the action by visiting a certain webpage.